# Pivot in Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, pivot

I have searched Stackoverflow about pivot in Oracle 11g but could not find the syntax that works for my situation.

Below is my query (runs in Oracle 11g).

```
select
age,
gender,
sum(hours) as hours
from table1
group by age, gender
```

Here is the O/P result

```
age gender   hours
25  Male     10
55  Female   5
45  Female   12
```

...And here is my desired O/P result

```
Age  Male   Female
25   10     0
45    0     12
55    0     5
```

...And here is my query

```
select *
from    
(
select
age,
gender,
sum(hours) as hours
from table1
)
pivot (
sum (hours) for gender in (
Male   as 'Male',
Female as 'Female')
)
```

...And here is the error:

```
ORA-00931: missing identifier
```

Could anyone please educate me please?

Comment: Not too familiar with pivot, but looks like you've got the quotes on the wrong side of the `as` in the pivot `in` clause (`'foo' as foo`)

Comment: `select *
from    
(
select
age,
gender,
sum(hours) as hours
from table1
)
pivot (
sum (hours) for gender in (
'Male','Female')
)`

Comment: Sure I did try it but the Male and Female columns show (null) as result.

Answer (score 4):

You were close:

```
select age, nvl(male, 0) male, nvl(female, 0) female
from    
(
  select age,  gender,  sum(hours) as hours
  from table1
  group by age, gender
)
pivot
(
  sum(hours) for gender in ('Male' as male, 'Female' as female)
);
```

Comment: @Emmanual, Thanks for your quick resonse! The query works. However, for some reason the sum(hours) function somehow does not sum the hours up. Instead the results show as 0 for MALE and FEMALE columns. Trouble shooting the reason why now.

Comment: You don't need `sum(hours)` or the `group by` in the sub-query. The pivot will do that for you.

Comment: Thank all! the script outputs the result as i desired. Joe

Answer (score 0):

The reason for 'missing identifier' error is - 
the expected syntax is

```
<Value> As <identifier>
```

So when you give -  Male   as 'Male' , it can not find the identifier after 'as' and hence gives this error.

Also even if you correct that error, the next error would come as "not a single-group group function" as you are selecting age and gender alongside aggregate function sum(hours) without grouping by (I just mentioned this as a technical point, you don't actually need any group by here).

Please refer to the below code for your output.

```
   SELECT age,nvl(male,0) AS male,nvl(female,0) AS frmale FROM 
    (SELECT * 
     FROM (
           SELECT age,gender,hours 
           FROM test_subha3) 
           pivot (sum(hours) FOR gender IN ('Male' AS Male,'Female' AS Female))
    )
```

Comment: ..updated my reply with an explanation. It now asnwers the original question and provides an alternate solution.